# Change site name text on the tab at top of Chrome, IE, etc. programmatically

Tags: javascript, php, web

I've redirected to an end site, the URL coincides with that end site page--but the tab still has the redirecting-site name text.  How can I use PHP, JavaScript (it would probably be that) or other to change the tab text for the end site that everything else is already finally on?

Comment: I don't see any way that's possible if you're actually redirecting. Is the URL in the location bar changing when you "redirect"? If not, what are you doing exactly?

Comment: I've just discovered since I posted that without doing anything more than I've already done, the tab reads correctly in IE. But nothing I do will make Chrome adopt a custom tab name.  I just want the tab to say "www.[whatever].com" like the URL does.

Comment: You're doing something strange. That behavior is not normal for Chrome.

Comment: I'm forwarding to an intermediary site to add a counter, then using window.top.location.href to send it on its final way.  IE picks up the final dest. in the tab's text without me doing anything more, but Chrome doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

are you asking something like these?

```
//using javscript
window.document.title="name";
*(OR)*
winRef.document.title
//using html
<head><title>name</title></head>
```

Comment: It would be like the window.document.title="name"; statement or the <title> tag--but neither of them work in Chrome for the forward I've done.  I've discovered just now that without doing anything more than I've already done, the tab reads correctly in IE.  But nothing I do will make Chrome adopt a new tab name.

Answer (score 0):

in every html page you can write the site name in title tag within head section.

by using javascript, you can also write as below:
document.title='yoursitename';